Do I attach my vinyl fence post to my house? If so, how should I go about it?
I have been doing a bunch of research and still can’t figure out what to do. I’m trying to install a vinyl fence for my mom but I already ran into an issue. Her house is on a slab and she has two dogs that love escaping so the post needs to by as close to the house as possible. There’s about a foot to a foot and a half of concrete hanging over and a few inches thick and it’s about 2-3 inches under the dirt. The concrete is very rough and not level at all.
I first tried putting down a concrete anchor with a few concrete screws and attaching a 4x4 piece of wood to it and sliding the post over the 4x4, but since the concrete isn’t smooth and isn’t level the post wasn’t level either, even with a few compost shims. I’ve been looking around and everyone says to never put screws into your siding but I don’t have very many options.
The first reason I see not to attach it to the house is because it can cause moisture to go through the holes. Everything that I’m seeing is for wood posts so I don’t think I’ll run into that issue especially if I put some kind of sealer around the screws that are going into the house.
The other issue that I see with this option is that all the weight or heavy winds could rip off your siding. I’d have to attach the post on both sides of the house. On one side I’m putting a gate but I’m not hanging the gate on the post attached to the house, it would be on the next post over that’ll be in cement with an aluminum post insert. The the post attached to the house will only have the latch and no insert so it won’t have any weight on it. The post on the other side of the house will have 8ft of vinyl fencing then I’m attaching another gate so the post on the other end again will have an aluminum insert in cement.
I honestly am not sure what to do since everyone says no but all the videos and articles that I’m reading are on wood fence posts and not vinyl. If anyone has suggestions it would help me out a lot.

A photo or two would sure help you out here.  Why can't you simply auger a hole for the post as close to the slab as possible, and fill any space between the post and house with pieces of vinyl?
